# Saving an Outlook message to a folder created in local drive by VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, save, message

I create a folder with VBA.

```
Sub ExtractEmail()

    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim Mailobject As Object
    Dim Email As String
    Dim NS As NameSpace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fldrname As String
    Dim fldrpath As String

    ' Setup Namespace
      Set NS = ThisOutlookSession.Session
    ' Display select folder dialog
      Set Folder = NS.PickFolder
    ' Create Folder File
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' loop to read email address from mail items.
    For Each Mailobject In Folder.Items
    fldrname = Mailobject.To
    fldrpath = "\\abc\" & fldrname
    If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
        fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
    End If

    Set objCopy = Mailobject.Copy
    objCopy.SaveAs fldrpath, olMSG

    Next
    Set OlApp = Nothing
    Set Mailobject = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I try to use

```
Mailobject.SaveAs fldrpath, olMSG
```

to save the mail into the folder, I cannot write to file.

Right clicking the folder, and then clicking properties on the shortcut menu to check permission of the folder, I see attribute as Read Only.

Could you please help me figure out the alternative?

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: If it's read only then you might want to consider changing the permission to Read and Write ?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a fully qualified file name to SaveAs. You are passing just the folder name:

```
objCopy.SaveAs fldrpath & "\test.msg", olMSG
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. :) Can you also help me on how to make this dynamic with respect to subject names of the mail. I used following syntax Subjectname = Mailobject.Subject but unable to fit in "\test.msg" you mentioned.

Comment: objCopy.SaveAs fldrpath & "\" & objCopy.Subject, olMSG. But you need to make sure there are no illegal (for a fiel name) characters, such as ":" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
fldrpath = "\\abc\" & fldrname & 
"\"
savepath = fldrpath & Mailobject.Subject & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-
hhNNss")
savepath = savepath & ".msg"

If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
End If


Set objCopy = Mailobject.Copy
objCopy.SaveAs savepath, olMSG
```

Comment: This code throws error operation failed at last line. Can anyone figure out the fix for the same? I am trying to copy the mail and paste it in savepath.